# Integer parameters formula returns integer

Tags: java, casting, int, long-integer, primitive

Code below makes foo value as `-1149239296` i. e. `integer` value which is out of bounds:

```
int bar = 3000;
long foo = bar * 1024 * 1024;
```

Seems like `Java` takes `type` of first parameter and tryes to return formula's result with that `type`.
Where in `Java` specification one can read that story?

I made such suggestion cause

```
int bar = 3000;
long foo = (long)bar * 1024 * 1024;
```

actually returns sets `long` value to `foo`.

Comment: `int * int = int`. Just cast any of the values to long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, casting any of the `int` literals to `long` will work.  But with longer chains of operators, where an overflow may occur somewhere in the middle, the associativity matters.  The `*` operator is left-associative, according to the [JLS Section 15.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17), so the first literal should be a `long` to avoid overflowing `int`s from the start.  Other math-related operators are also left-associative.

The reason that only one of the literals being `long` is necessary is because of *binary numeric promotion*, [Section 5.6.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), which will promote the narrower type to the wider type, at least `int`.

Comment: Accepted bacause of reference to `Java` standart.